# How to catch select event of table cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have an **UIViewController** where I have placed some single table cells. Most of them are just a nice way to display data which does not allow any interaction. But now I added a cell which needs to be clicked to open another view.

[image]

How can I see that the cell was clicked? How do I implement that?

Comment: It's very strange to build UI based on UITableViewCells without UITableView.

Comment: than point it out in an answer instead of voting down the question...

Comment: If you don't want to use UITableView - use buttons. Set to them required background image and assign for each a target method. It's a simplest way. But if you make table.. use UITableView class. You can use it in UIViewController. We had provided links and one of delegate methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to implement the delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //where indexPath.row is the selected cell
}
```

Comment: are  your sure this is right? My class is a UIViewController class. When I use the UITableViewDelegate and implement this method and select a cell nothing happens...

Comment: I  think it is not possible to set the delegate of a table cell

Comment: You need to set yar delegate first either from Interface Builder or from code.In ViewDidLoad you can set yarTable.delegate=self. From IB just right click on the tableView,drag and drop the delegate and the datasource to FilesOwner if u didn't.

Comment: never mind. I make the last cell a button and the problem is gone

Comment: yup...i am just going to tell that...i mean using a transparent button...

in this case better to use UITableView to get the exact flavor.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

See also docs - [UITableViewDataSource Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3acellForRowAtIndexPath%3a)

Answer (score 0):

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
    (NSIndexPath *)
indexPath

{

//where indexPath.row is the selected cell

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showMobileDetail" sender:indexPath];

}

Comment: you must mention your index path at sender...it works..!